# Unexpected Doctest result for an output including a backslash

Tags: python, doctest

This doctest fails with an output shown at the bottom. Why does Pytest change the doctest to `strip_special_chars( "c:\abcDEF1 23-_@.sql")` with a single backslash leading to the unintended expected result? How do I change its behavior?

```
def strip_special_chars(input_text, re_string='[^a-zA-Z0-9_\s\.\-:\\\\]'):
    """
    >>> strip_special_chars( "c:\\abcDEF1 23-_@.sql")
    'c:\\abcDEF1 23-_.sql'
    """
    regex = re.compile(re_string) 
    return regex.sub('', input_text)
```

```
_____________________________________________ [doctest] helpers.strip_special_chars _____________________________________________ 
1484
1485     >>> strip_special_chars( "c:\abcDEF1 23-_@.sql")
Expected:
    'c:\abcDEF1 23-_.sql'
Got:
    'c:bcDEF1 23-_.sql'
```

Comment: \ is called a escaped character. To escape a escape character you would do \\

Comment: But the doctest already has two \s.

Comment: I don't follow what you're actually trying to do here. All of those characters are unicode characters. They're also all ascii characters. What are you actually intending your function to do?

Comment: The string is programmatically generated, and sometimes it includes weird unicode characters, so I'm writing this function to strip them out.

Comment: **Again**, what do you *specifically* mean by "weird unicode characters"? The `@` symbol isn't a "weird unicode character" to me... your test input seems to be a Windows file path. `Path` [is a thing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) if that's what you're dealing with...

Comment: Changed the function name to "strip_special_chars" to avoid confusion.

Comment: I had the same problem some time ago, and user2357112 answer on the dupe did a good job of explaining what was actually happening here. Adding the r prefix on the docstring is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `r` to the doctest string fixed it. Because the argument ("c:\abcDEF1 23-_@.sql") is inside """, it appears that `\\` changes to `\` (thereby having no escaping) before Pytest sees it.

```
def strip_special_chars(input_text, re_string='[^a-zA-Z0-9_\s\.\-:\\\\]'):
    r"""
    >>> strip_special_chars( "c:\\abcDEF1 23-_@.sql")
    'c:\\abcDEF1 23-_.sql'
    """
    regex = re.compile(re_string) 
    return regex.sub('', input_text)
```